# Is "Cafeé und Thée Logia" partly Italian?

Tags: etymology, single-words, history, spelling, accents

There has been a discussion of the phrase "Cafeé und Thée Logia" seen in a C18(?) picture on the [German Language Stack Exchange](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/48328/was-bedeutet-th%C3%A9e-auf-deutsch). None of the words is a modern spelling in any language except *und* which is German for "and".

So far we have got:

*Cafeé* looks more like French *café* than Italian *caffè* but the [Académie française](https://academie.atilf.fr/9/consulter/caf%C3%A9?page=1) derives *café* from Italian *caveé*, *caffé*. *Cafeé* looks half way in between.

*Und* is German for "and".

*Thée* looks like the French *thé* but this seems to have been the early spelling in Italian as the Italian [*tè*](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%C3%A8) comes from French. The second *e* is unexplained.

[*Loggia*](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loggia) is Italian from Latin, and is usually spelt with *gg*, at least in Latin, Italian, French and German:

> [Wikidata item](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q466544) 
>   English: loggia, 
>   French: loggia, 
>   German: Loggia, Loggien, 
>   Afrikaans: Loggia, 
>   Belarusian: Лоджыя, 
>   Belarusian: Лёджыя, 
>   Bulgarian: Лоджия, 
>   Catalan: loggia, 
>   Czech: lodžie, Loggie, 
>   Danish: Loggia, 
>   Emiliano-Romagnolo: Lóśa, 
>   Esperanto: loĝio, 
>   Spanish: logia, loggia, 
>   Estonian: Lodža, Loggia, 
>   Basque: Logia, Loggia, 
>   Finnish: Loggia, 
>   Gan (Traditional): Loggia, 
>   Galician: Loggia, 
>   Hebrew: לוג'יה, 
>   Hungarian: Loggia, 
>   Armenian: Լոջիա, 
>   Ido: Lojio, 
>   Italian: loggia, logge, 
>   Japanese: ロッジア, 開廊, 
>   涼み廊下, 
>   涼み廊, 
>   Georgian: ლოჯია, 
>   Kyrgyz: Лоджия, 
>   Latin: Loggia, 
>   Norwegian Bokmål: loggia, 
>   Dutch: loggia, 
>   Polish: Loggia, 
>   Portuguese: lógia, logia, 
>   loggia, 
>   Romanian: Logie, 
>   Russian: Лоджия, 
>   Slovak: Lodžia, Loggia, 
>   Slovenian: Loža, 
>   Swedish: Loggia, 
>   Ukrainian: Лоджія, 
>   Chinese: 涼廊,

Can someone with a knowledge of old spellings in Italian please say if these are valid Italian spellings and, if so, from when? And if *eé* is valid, what is the *é* for?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: None of those three words seems to be any form usual in present or past Italian. My feeling as a native Italian is that they intend to be Italian, from someone who didn't know the language, and copied or remembered them incorrectly. For instance, CAFEÉ looks like CAFFÈ mistaking a F for an E, and using a random accent. Then again, Italian spelling didn't use to be fixed in stone, and accents in particular oscillated.

Comment: @DaG That's a good point about CAFEÉ looking like CAFFÉ. *Cafeé* looked pretty strange to me until I saw the reference in the French dictionary to Italian *caveé*. Do you think this is an error? Was accent direction arbitrary? Did you ever see *eé* or *eè*?

Comment: _Caveé_ doesn't ring any bell, but I'm not at home now. I'll check and let you know.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Nothing is impossible, but I read a fair amount of old Italian books and I've never seen the digraph *eé*. I concur with DaG that this is what someone thought Italian looked like, although it's not even close, and if anything it resembles French. *Logia* is possible: the representation of geminate consonants has been very irregular in written Italian, especially in the North (where they did not exist as actual sounds).

Comment: @DavidRobinson Honestly, I wouldn't take the Academie Française as a reference for Italian either :). Honestly in my opinion is that someone messed up pretty badly while doing that engraving. There were incompetents also back in the day :)

Comment: @DavidRobinson *ée is totally alien to French* Did you mean to write *eé*? *ée* appears in many French words (mainly from the past participle ending *é* + feminine ending *e*).

Comment: Yes, @Denisnardin, but you would hope that the Académie française could at least copy a word correctly from wherever they got it from. And how do you know it was the engraver not the sign-writer that messed up?

Comment: Yes, @denisnardin. We all agreed with you on German SE until I found that the Académie française was citing the Italian word caveé in their most recent dictionary. Hopefully they wouldn't "think that's what Italian looks like". eé is totally alien to French. As for Logia we English speakers tend to forget that spelling is related to pronunciation in any way - we would never change the spelling just because the pronunciation changes! But what you say makes for a language where they do match

Comment: I feel that *thée* must come from a Germanic language, if it's not French (which I don't think so).

Comment: Yes, @ibug, *thee* can be German but German doesn't have acute accents and I'm not aware of any Germanic languages that do. Out could be confusion between French *thé* and older German *thee*.

Answer (score 4):

The only occurrence I could find of a spelling similar to *cafeé* in an Italian text is *caveè*, in a report by 16th-century cardinal and ambassador Gianfrancesco Morosini, as quoted in [*Le relazioni degli ambasciatori veneti al Senato raccolte, annotate ed edite da Eugenio Alberi*](https://books.google.it/books?id=zkdcUQ-4MY8C&pg=PA268&dq=%22cave%C3%A9%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwil_ZrUl57fAhWG2ywKHcEBAo8Q6AEIXjAI#v=onepage&q=%22cave%C3%A9%22&f=false) (1855). Speaking about Turks after his mission in Constantinople, he wrote in 1585:

> Quasi di continuo stanno a sedere, e per trattenimento usano di bere pubblicamente, così nelle botteghe come anco per le strade, non solo uomini bassi ma ancora de' più principali, un'acqua negra bollente quanto possono sofferire, che si cava d'una semente che chiaman Caveè, la quale dicono che ha virtù di far stare l'uomo svegliato.

More or less: They, both high- and low-class men, continuously drink in bars and streets a boiling-hot black water obtained by a seed they call *Caveè*, which they say keeps men awake.

The 19th-century editor annotates that it is the first time an Italian writer mentions coffee, using its Turkish name, “cahveh” (apparently, the modern Turkish spelling is [*kahve*](https://tr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahve)).

So, technically, at least an Italian writer (almost) used that spelling to designate coffee. It seems, however, that it was just a tentative first version that didn't take root, while subsequently only versions more similar to *caffè* or *café* were used. For instance, the authoritative dictionary of the Accademia della Crusca includes [*caffè*](http://www.lessicografia.it/Controller?E=54;103335908;&c1=113;-7;3;-176437357;-1092164176;&c2=129;28;3;40;69;1;130;32;5;40;66;1;129;28;65;-9;69;1;130;1025;5;40;73;4;130;27;3;872224124;-1604222224;&qi=&q1=null&q2=null&q3=null&q4=null&qr=null&num=20&o=115;-38489505;-1185594668;&idV=943901;1123572173;-338795348;&TDE=&TDNE=) since its third edition, published in 1691 (where it appears in the *Giunte*, Addenda, while in subsequent editions *caffè* appears as a normal lemma).

As for tea, the spelling of its name is quite uncertain even in modern Italian, so I assume some leeway may be possible for past centuries, where orthography was still in progress. Nowadays vocabularies record two or three spellings (Treccani, for instance, takes [*tè*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/te1/) as its lemma, and lists as “less common” spellings *the* and *thè*). I can find the version *Theè* in [late-17th-century text](https://books.google.it/books?id=TlNTGAETMXYC&pg=PA145&dq=%22the%C3%A8%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiWt4OSpqXfAhUIGuwKHY7tBfMQ6AEIPTAD#v=onepage&q=%22the%C3%A8%22&f=false):

> Si parla finalmente della Beuanda del Theè, e si espongono le sue Virtú singolari; Si mostra, che i tartari Orientali la beuanda del Theè formano col'latte, e sale ...

(They talk about *Theè* drink and its singular virtues; Oriental Tartars make it with milk and salt.)

Again, I can't find other occurrences (other ones in Google Books turn out to be other languages, among which Latin, or artefacts due to OCR). Crusca records just *tè* (giving *the* as its Latin form) only from its [fourth edition](http://www.lessicografia.it/Controller?E=1078;1756404708;&c1=350;-7;3;-21159276;212722725;&c2=129;-39;3;40;69;1;130;32;5;40;66;1;129;-39;65;-31;69;4;130;1025;5;40;75;13;130;27;3;1646876352;1545561153;&qi=&q1=@the&q2=&q3=&q4=&qr=null&num=20&o=115;-38489505;-1185594668;&idV=1506603;-8;-2135859001;-1687727295;&TDE=@the;&TDNE=) (1729-1738). (Earlier lemmas refer to homographs.)

Finally, I can't find anything for *logia*, and my instinct suggests me that it is a misspelling (or local, not widespread spelling) by either a foreigner or a Northern Italian, but I can't find a definite answer.

Comment: Thank you, @dag What would *ee* mean? Could it be meant to represent two separate vowels? Since the original Italian spelling would likely have been an attempt at representing the Turkish, I looked up [*kahve*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kahve) and it is pronounced /'kɑhve/. This did not explain the *eé* but then I noticed that is has inflections: definite accusative kahveyi, plural kahveler. If you wanted to drink the coffee, then kahveyi would be form. Could *eé*, or any other form with two letters *e* be an attempt at rendering Turkish *eyi* (for which I have not found a pronunciation)?

Comment: Great research!

Comment: @DavidRobinson: No Italian word with “eé” comes to my mind, but there are several with just “ee” (mostly the plural of words ending in _-ea_, such as _dea_. _rea_, _marea_ and many more: _dee_, _ree_, _maree_...) and the two “e”s definitely denote a doubled vowel.

Comment: @DaG It's worth mentioning that those words carry the stress on the *first* vowel, so that *-eè* could be an attempt to represent a doubled vowel with the stress on the second one. In any case it's almost certainly an attempt to represent Turkish pronunciation, rather than a genuine Italian word.

Comment: Thank you DaG and @DenisNardin I'm beginning to fit the jigsaw together. How about this: the word came from Turkish as the C18 equivalent of both *kahve* and kahvehi (which appears to be pronounced roughly [as written](https://forvo.com/word/kahveyi/#tr)). Since *é* is a better approximation to the *i* in *kahveyi* than *e*/*è*, *caveé* would be a good attempt at *kahveyi*. *Cavè*/*kahve* and *caveé/*kahveyi* would both have been in use and apparently *cavè* took over. The reason for the *f* is not yet obvious.